# Using mechanize to upload files to Sharepoint is failing, I can't figure out why

Tags: python, sharepoint, mechanize

Below is the code that I am using. Can anybody please tell me what I am missing here?

```
br.select_form("aspnetForm")
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
FILENAME="2BProcessed.txt"
#br['ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$InputFile']=FILENAME
br.form.add_file(open(FILENAME), 'text/plain', FILENAME)

print br.form
print "------------------------------------------------"
br.method="POST"
response = br.submit()
#print response.read()
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

and here is what the forms look like before (empty), when a file is selected, and finally after submiting the form

Form before posting

```
<aspnetForm POST httP://server.addrees.removed... multipart/form-data
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_View=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_ShowSettings=False) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_FilterString=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_Button=none) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName=Browse) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTTARGET=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTARGUMENT=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_Shared=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_LayoutChanges=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_InDesignMode=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName=Browse) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__REQUESTDIGEST=0x86FE3811F793DC67C1CA3282A8213erwerC0CD91108B06F41D5C600B09C3A22E0661289A176933917B7D6786859B7717A924AE49E31E5C4B9A01DD25A2EC2,28 Jul 2015 15:52:24 -0000) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__VIEWSTATE=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) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWCgLi07123123pn5bCCwLreQLNrvW5AwLY47yCDQKMpf/RBQL7opj3BAKLy4KjDQLHnuf8DwLI6ZCjDAC/5mtuxuY2gn08bbL4JgmPox8f) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl00=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl01=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$S3031AEBB_InputKeywords=Search this site...)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl05=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(destination=/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents/Data) (readonly)>
  <FileControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$InputFile=<No files added>)>
  <CheckboxControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$OverwriteSingle=[*on])>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$uploadLocation=/Data/)>
  <SubmitControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$selectTargetButton=Choose Folder...) (readonly)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$RptControls$btnOK=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$BtnCancel=<None>)>
  <TextControl(__spText1=)>
  <TextControl(__spText2=)>>

Forme before submitting it:

<aspnetForm POST httP://server.addrees.removed04693Ka00000878 ...multipart/form-data
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_View=0)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_ShowSettings=False)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_FilterString=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_Button=none)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName=Browse)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode=false)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTTARGET=)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTARGUMENT=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_Shared=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_LayoutChanges=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_InDesignMode=)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName=Browse)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName=false)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing=false)>
  <HiddenControl(_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition=0)>
  <HiddenControl(__REQUESTDIGEST=0x86FE3811F793DC67C1CA3282A4324325BE6BACC0CD91108B06F41D5C600B09C3A22E0661289A176933917B7D6786859B7717A924AE49E31E5C4B9A01DD25A2EC2,28 Jul 2015 15:52:24 -0000)>
  <HiddenControl(__VIEWSTATE=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)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWCgLi07HcCgKpn5bCCwLEiLTXBQLNrvertyCDQKMpf/RBQL7opj3BAKLy4KjDQLHnuf8DwLI6ZCjDAC/5mtuxuY2gn08bbL4JgmPox8f)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl00=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl01=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents)>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$S3031AEBB_InputKeywords=Search this site...)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl05=0)>
  <HiddenControl(destination=/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents/Data)>
  <FileControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$InputFile=2BProcessed.txt)>
  <CheckboxControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$OverwriteSingle=[*on])>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$uploadLocation=/Data/)>
  <SubmitControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$selectTargetButton=Choose Folder...)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$RptControls$btnOK=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$BtnCancel=<None>)>
  <TextControl(__spText1=)>
  <TextControl(__spText2=)>>

  -------------Form after  using .submit() -----------------------------------

<aspnetForm POSThttP://server.addrees.removed04693Ka00000878/_layouts/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7bDAD046C2-93DB-47E9-85D1-B37BA16BC0F0%7d&RootFolder=%2fwnp0%2f04693Ka00000878%2fShared+Documents%2fWiFi+Installation+Data multipart/form-data
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_View=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_ShowSettings=False) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOGallery_FilterString=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOTlPn_Button=none) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName=Browse) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTTARGET=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTARGUMENT=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOWebPartPage_Shared=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_LayoutChanges=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOLayout_InDesignMode=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName=Browse) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing=false) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__REQUESTDIGEST=0x86FE3811F793DC67C1CA3282A84C015BE6BACC0CD91108B06F41D5C600B09C3A22E0661289A176933917B7D6786859B7717A924AE49E31E5C4B9A01DD25A2EC2,28 Jul 2015 15:52:24 -0000) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__VIEWSTATE=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) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWCgKctKHNAgKpn5bCCwLEiLTXBQLNrvW5AwLY47yCDQKMpf/RBQL7opj3BAKLy4KjDQLHnuf8DwLI6ZCjDLQQtRpJaA+c51Db8+nAhd28gOn9) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl00=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl01=https://server.address.removed/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$S3031AEBB_InputKeywords=Search this site...)>
  <HiddenControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl05=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(destination=/wnp0/04693Ka00000878/Shared Documents/Data) (readonly)>
  <FileControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$InputFile=<No files added>)>
  <CheckboxControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl03$OverwriteSingle=[*on])>
  <TextControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$uploadLocation=/Data/)>
  <SubmitControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl04$ctl02$selectTargetButton=Choose Folder...) (readonly)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$RptControls$btnOK=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$BtnCancel=<None>)>
  <TextControl(__spText1=)>
  <TextControl(__spText2=)>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dear friend you may be forgot to update command after submit file into the list. Your mechanize is perfect just add update command after post and submit. **after below : response = br.submit()**